# Объединить два запроса sql с сортировкой во втором

Tags: sql

Есть две таблицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выполняю запрос

```
SELECT p.image 
FROM oc_product p 
WHERE product_id = '31' 
UNION (SELECT pim.image 
FROM oc_product_image pim 
WHERE product_id = '31' 
ORDER BY `sort_order` ASC)
```

Т.е. сортировка во втором запросе не работает, либо работает но в запросе все равно выводит не отсортированное

Comment: сначала объединяйте, потом сортируйте

Comment: Попробуйте `UNION ALL` вместо простого `UNION`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715820/how-to-order-by-with-union

Comment: UNION ALL и UNION результат одинаков

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для получения искомого рузультата в качестве значения поля сортировки из первой таблицы выберите `-1`: `-1 AS sort_order`:

```
(SELECT p.image, -1 AS sort_order 
FROM oc_product AS p 
WHERE product_id = '31')

UNION 

(SELECT pim.image, sort_order 
FROM oc_product_image pim 
WHERE product_id = '31') 

ORDER BY `sort_order` ASC
```

либо для выборки только одного поля, используя подзапрос:

```
SELECT d.image 
FROM (
    SELECT p.image, -1 AS sort_order 
    FROM oc_product AS p 
    WHERE product_id = '31'

    UNION 

    SELECT pim.image, sort_order 
    FROM oc_product_image pim 
    WHERE product_id = '31'
) as d
ORDER BY d.sort_order ASC
```

Comment: Огромная благодарность, все получилось!

Comment: @DmitryMoskvitin пожалуйста :) Можете отметить ответ как правильный.

Comment: >> @DmitryMoskvitin пожалуйста :) Можете отметить ответ как правильный. – teran 3 минуты назад - А как это сделать?

Comment: Для выборки одного поля не работает, выводит без сортировки

Comment: Хотя нет, ошибаюсь, для вывода одного поля тоже корректно работает, прошу прощения.